# Render Jade view without Response Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have a complex chain of async callbacks and during any point in the chain, if there's an error, I'd like to render a Jade template with the error message.

In the function partnerErr below, is it possible to respond with a template without the original response object?

```
app.post('/dashboard/partners/create', function (req, res) {
    console.log( req.body );

    ParseUtils.doesUserExist( 
        req.body.partnerEmail, 
        function() { ShopifyUtils.doesPartnerExist( req.body.partnerShopSlug, 
                function() { ParseUtils.createUser( req.body, 
                    function() { ShopifyUtils.createPartner( req.body, 
                        res.send( ' all good. parse and shopify passed. user created. '),
                        partnerErr
                    ); },
                    partnerErr 
                ); },
                partnerErr
            ); 
        },
        partnerErr
    );
});

function partnerErr(err) {
    console.log( 'rendering partner error' );
    app.render('admin/partnersCreate', { error : err }, function(err, html) {
        console.log('html', html);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I would take a look at https://github.com/caolan/async to clean up your series of async calls. That many nested is almost unreadable. It looks like `series` or `waterfall` would suite your needs here. This would also drastically cut down the number of times you need to write `partnerErr` and move all of the error checking logic into one place.

That being said, why not just pass `res` into `partnerErr` and use `res.render`? Am I understanding your question correctly?

**UPDATE**

I would strongly encourage you to consider rewriting this as I said above, however, if you want to leave it alone, you could do something like this:

```
app.post('/dashboard/partners/create', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);

  ParseUtils.doesUserExist(
    req.body.partnerEmail,
    function() {
      ShopifyUtils.doesPartnerExist(req.body.partnerShopSlug,
        function() {
          ParseUtils.createUser(req.body,
            function() {
              ShopifyUtils.createPartner(req.body,
                res.send(' all good. parse and shopify passed. user created. '),
                partnerErr(res)
              );
            },
            partnerErr(res)
          );
        },
        partnerErr(res)
      );
    },
    partnerErr(res)
  );
});

function partnerErr(res) {
  return function(err) {
    console.log('rendering partner error');
    res.render('admin/partnersCreate', {
      error: err
    });
  }
}
```

Another option would be to move the `partnerErr` function into the same scope as the `app.post` and just have access to the `res` variable. I'm not sure how decoupled the `partnerErr` truly is based just on this snippet.

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful! If I pass res to partnerErr, do I also need to pass it through each successive callback so when one of the steps fails, it can be called back such as: error( err, res )?

Comment: ah good, the async call solves my res.render issue, but i suppose technically not the question. is there a way to instantiate a new response from app.render()?

in this case, it looks like two calls to async.series() will work. one to validate for both Parse and Shopify and another to POST new partners to each API. thanks again